# how to find the last quarter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

This should be a simple question but I still cannot get some valid result.
I'm using the Workbench.
I'm trying to get the last quarter from the current date.

When I query the current quarter, I get the right answer:

```
SELECT quarter(curdate());
1
```

But when I want the last quarter:

```
SELECT (quarter(curdate())-1);
```

I still get 1.

I also tried (found it online):

```
SELECT LAST_QTR(curdate());
```

but I get:

```
Error code: 1305. FUNCTION LAST_QTR does not exist
```

Can someone help figure this out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the result for `curdate()-1`? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I think the OP wanted to get '0' as the return value. Though I believe the way that `code`SELECT (quarter(curdate())-1);`code` was formatted, your select statement becomes `code`SELECT 0`code`, which isn't very helpful

Comment: the code you are showing works fine. but I guess you are actually using something else

Comment: When I type: SELECT quarter(curdate()-1); I still get 1 instead of 4 for last quarter...

Comment: You most likely are thinking of quarter(curdate())-1. Which doesn't quite work out without an IF for when the quarter is currently 1. What you are typing quarter(curdate()-1) is the quarter of yesterday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this and see if this works for you.

```
SELECT quarter(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER);
```

Comment: Thank you Abi, I just spent 2 hours to get that.

Answer (score 2):

Get Last Quarter End Date

```
SELECT CASE WHEN QUARTER(curdate()) = 1 
            THEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 1)  + INTERVAL 4 QUARTER - INTERVAL    1 DAY 
            ELSE MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)+ INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) - 1 QUARTER - INTERVAL    1 DAY  END
```

Replace the `Curdate()` with the `date` you needed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`SELECT IF((QUARTER(curdate())-1) = 0, 4, QUARTER(curdate()) - 1) as last_quarter`

Return the current quarter - 1 if the quarter is greater than 1. Otherwise if the current quarter is 1 return 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get all the previous/last quarter records in MySql or WordPress.

**Note : `visited` is the datetime column into the table**

`"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE QUARTER(visited) = QUARTER(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 quarter)"`